# Returning HashMap of results in MyBatis (rather than List)

Tags: mybatis

Can MyBatis return a HashMap of results, instead of a List?
e.g. given a table:

```
foo  | bar
 1   |  a
 2   |  b
```

and a query

```
SELECT foo, bar FROM foobar
```

Return a result of `HashMap<String, String> map` where `map.get(1) == 'a'`, `map.get(2) == 'b'` etc?

I've tried variations on the following:

```
    <resultMap id="hashMapResult" type="java.util.HashMap">
       <id  column="foo"  />
       <result property="bar" column="bar"/>
    </resultMap>

    <select id="personStatuses" resultMap="hashMapResult">
      SELECT foo, bar FROM foobar
    </select>
```

But just get the error: `Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: ...`

Where tables have primary keys, it would be more useful to be able to get the results as a Map of PK => row, than just a List of rows.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pivot your table, let column `foo`'s rows as column, `Mybatis` can not do this, but you can use sql to achieve this(here is a `mysql` solution):

```
select
    max(case when foo = 1, then bar else null end) as `1`,
    max(case when foo = 2, then bar else null end) as `2`
from foobar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like below and your multiple results will be handled without any problem.

```
// in your mapper XML
<select id="personStatuses" resultType="java.util.HashMap" >
         SELECT foo, bar FROM foobar
</select>

// From Java code - list of hashmaps
List<HashMap> personStatuses =  yourMyBatisDao.personStatuses();

sysout(personStatuses);
```

Comment: That just returns a List like normal, not a HashMap of PK => row