# How to get Map result From mybatis sql with "group by"?

Tags: java, mybatis

```
 @Select({
        "<script>",
        "SELECT tag_id as tagId, count(*) as count FROM table_1",
        "where poi_id=#{poiId} and spu_id=#{spuId} and tag_id in ",
        "<foreach collection='tagIdList' item='tagId' index='index' open='(' separator = ',' close=')' >",
        "#{tagId}",
        "</foreach>",
        " group by tag_id ",
        "</script>"
})
@ResultType(HashMap.class)
Map<Long, Integer> getMap(@Param("poiId") long poiId, @Param("spuId") long spuId
        , @Param("tagIdList") List<Long> tagIdList)
```

with the above sql, I get the following error

org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.TooManyResultsException: Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 2

what is wrong and how to fix this? thanks!

Comment: The return type `Map<Long, Integer>` is not valid. Try changing the return type to `List<Map<String, Object>>`. If that is not what you want, you may have to create a DTO (a custom class to store the result) and use it as the return type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning HashMap of results in MyBatis (rather than List)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38187324/returning-hashmap-of-results-in-mybatis-rather-than-list)